# Python raw_input not working

Tags: python

I'm just getting started in programming and am trying to learn Python. The last part of Chapter four, exercise 5, of `how to think like a computer scientist` is stumping me. I'm trying to modify the shell script so that a user can enter 'a', 'b', or 'c' and the correct response will print out base on user choice. This is how I have it implemented so far,  and was hoping someone could tell me what I'm missing here.

```
def dispatch(choice):
    if choice == 'a':
        function_a()
    elif choice == 'b':
        function_b()
    elif choice == 'c':
        function_c()
    else:
    print "Invalid choice."

def function_a():
    print "function_a was called ..."

def function_b():
    print "function_b was called ..."

def function_c():
    print "function_c was called ..."

dispatch1 = raw_input ("Please Enter a Function.")
print dispatch(choice)
```

When I run this I get name choice is not defined error.  I'm trying to get it to spit back function_b was called... when it is entered into the raw_input.

Thank you for any help,

John

Comment: You haven't defined `choice`, you called it `dispatch1`.

Comment: Please try to think of a better title—what made you think that `raw_input` was the problem?

Comment: Voting to close, as this is simply a problem with using the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're taking input and assigning it to dispatch1, not choice:

```
choice = raw_input ("Please Enter a Function.")
print dispatch(choice)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,  something so simple was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

James is correct (as is Lattyware as well). Since you are still learning, I thought it might help to give a bit more information on what you are seeing.

The parameter to dispatch is a variable. Inside the function call itself, it is called "choice". When you captured the input using raw_input, you are currently saving it as a variable named "dispatch1". Choice is undefined at the time where you called dispatch (though, since it is called choice in the function definition, it is a little confusing). The fact that it is undefined is the cause of your error.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on that.

Answer (score 0):

A working example.. By the way, take care of Indentation in python.

```
def dispatch(choice):
    if choice == 'a':
        function_a()
    elif choice == 'b':
        function_b()
    elif choice == 'c':
        function_c()
    else:
        print "Invalid choice."

def function_a():
    print "function_a was called ..."
def function_b():
    print "function_b was called ..."
def function_c():
    print "function_c was called ..."

choice = raw_input ("Please Enter a Function.")
dispatch(choice)
```